# why werkzeug (invoked via flask) doesn't log when its run via wcgi IIS?

Tags: python, flask, iis

if I run a simple flask app via python console specifying host and port, then it logs werkzeug messages, e.g. during startup it shows smt along

INFO - werkzeug - _log -  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

when I run the same via IIS fastcgi, dropping port parameter from app.run(), all logs are kept, flask, my app, 3rd party apps, all levels, except the werkzeug. What's happening here? Why the (not) including port affect logs? Port is set via IIS and all works when done that way.

code (in console)

```
#vanilla python logging
import sys
import logging
log = logging.getLogger()  # create logger (or get if existing) and name this instance
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
consoleLog = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
consoleLog.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) #level for console handler
my_format=logging.Formatter(
                            fmt="{asctime} - {levelname} - {name} - {funcName} - {message}",
                            style="{",
                            datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
consoleLog.setFormatter(my_format)
log.addHandler(consoleLog)  # add this handler (console) to the logger

fileLog = logging.FileHandler("d:\logs\primitive_app_IIS.log")
fileLog.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fileLog.setFormatter(my_format)
log.addHandler(fileLog)

#flask setup
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"

log.info('check log works IIS ')
#run the app
app.run(port = 5096)
```

if in wsgi.py file (that is used by IIS) I use same code but change last line to drop parameters that are handled by IIS

```
app.run()
```

then all works, but no werkzeug logs. If I use 'app.run(port = 5096)' in IIS wcgi.py as well - different than my IIS site - then it starts to log werkzeug msgs as well into primitive_app_IIS.log , however it doesn't work further up (due to different ports I guess) If I use app.run(port = 5000)' in IIS wcgi.py - same as my IIS site -  app works again, but no werkzeug logs